# Fullcalendar events color MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I can pass the single resource color to the fullcalendar editing the "eventColor: '#00000'"

This is my code

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {   
       
        $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2021-01-12',
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, 
            events: '/events.php',           
            eventColor: '#00000',
         
        });            
   }); 
</script>
```

and this is my events.php that make the consult on BD

```
    <?php

//load.php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd_trabalhos', 'root', '');

$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM trabalho_v2 ORDER BY trabalho_id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["trabalho_id"],
  'title'   => $row["titulo_trabalho"],
  'start'   => $row["trabalho_recebido"],
  'end'   => $row["data_entregar"],
  'cor'   => $row["cor_cliente"]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

But i'm brand new with PHP and would like to know the best way to inject my colors from MySQL on this resource to show on my Calendar each event with ur color since the parameter "eventColor" applies to all events and not just to a specific event.

i will appreciate help and tips

Comment: Any reason, if you've just started this work, that you're using such an old version of fullCalendar? v4 has come and gone, and v5 has been available for nearly a year.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using this:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["trabalho_id"],
  'title'   => $row["titulo_trabalho"],
  'start'   => $row["trabalho_recebido"],
  'end'   => $row["data_entregar"],
  'color'   => $row["cor_cliente"]
 );
}
```

[image]

[Event Source Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/event-source-object)